# MVVM - How to cleanly incorporate AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-mvvm

I have a `FragmentOne` which contains the MVVM pattern. The `Fragment` has it's own `ViewModel`, `FragmentOneViewModel`. I am unsure on how to cleanly incorporate an `AlertDialog` in my case.

In the Fragment it contains a RecyclerViewAdapter, with each row that contains a Button to create an AlertDialog. Do I need a ViewModel for the AlertDialog?

Or can I use an interface callback and implement it on my Fragment, which will be called when the user clicks on buttons in the AlertDialog. And then use that input to call the Fragment's ViewModel?:

```
public class ActivateUserDialog extends AlertDialog {
    
    //Should I use callback methods?
    private Context mContext;

    public interface DialogOnClickListener{
        void onCancelBtnClick();
        void onConfirmBtnClick(String amount);
    }
    
    public ActivateUserDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_activate);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        
    }
    
    @OnClick(R.id.btn_cancel)
    public void onBtnDismiss() {
        this.dismiss();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_confirm)
    public void onBtnConfirm() {
        //Call the fragment 
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) mContext;
        MembersFragment fragment = (MembersFragment) .... get the fragment;
        fragment.onConfirmBtnClick(amount);
    }

}
```

And then calling the viewmodel from the callback method:

```
//Fragment class:

public class MembersFragment extends Fragment implements ActivateUserDialog.DialogOnClickListener

@Override
    public void onConfirmBtnClick(String amount){
        mViewModel.activateUser(amount);
    }
```

Is this a clean way to do it?

Comment: You can use `Dialog` class with custom layout. For Example:     Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.edit_box);
                                    Button cancel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I don't understand what that means

Comment: I have edit it.

Comment: I still don't quite understand how to cleanly implement that into MVVM

Comment: OK let me post an answer with recycler-view exmaple.

Comment: `I have a FragmentOne which contains the MVVM pattern` this already seems to be a misunderstanding. fragments dont contain architecture patterns, projects do. your entire project has an architecture, not just one fragment. you understand that fragments form _part_ of your entire architecture, right ?

Comment: let me clear this you want to use a dialog box on some click in recycler-view adapter which is based on MVVM pattern and want some callback on adapter after dialog box action right?

Comment: Yes this is what I am doing in my code above, but I don't know if this is the best practice way to do it with Dialog

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE  As I think its a good way easy to understand and maintainable.

Comment: @IvanWooll ah ok, thanks confirming it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a single answer to it and would say it's opinionated. Both would be valid in my opinion.

You also need to consider that architecture components don't work "out of the box" with AlertDialogs, so even if you want a VM for it you will have to retrieve it through the fragment/activity (basically a [ViewModelProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider)) or use some other solution like DI.
You would also have to manage the lifecycle of the AlertDialog to gain some of the benefits of the ViewModel.

Here are possible solutions:

1. Consider the AlertDialog as part of the View of FragmentOne and communicate with it via callbacks. In the implementation communicate with FragmentOneViewModel.
2. Use a [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/dialogs) with a ViewModel instead. Since DialogFragment is basically just a Fragment you get all the benefits of the architecture components ViewModel. You can either share FragmentOneViewModel between the two or create a new ViewModel dedicated to the dialog. Whether to share or create a new one is up to your needs but I would consider the complexity of the Dialog and whether it should be stand-alone. If you decide to share the ViewModel, be careful which [ViewModelProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider) you use to make sure they are actually shared and not a different instance.

As for communicating back from the AlertDialog, I would suggest using an interface with callbacks instead of passing Context and casting directly.
You can accept an implementation in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `dialog box` on some click in `recycler-view adapter` which is based on MVVM pattern and want some **callback** on adapter after dialog box action right?

> Yes this is what I am doing in my code above, but I don't know if
> this is the best practice way to do it with Dialog – DIRTY DAVE

As I think its a good way `easy to understand` and `maintainable`. However, `dialog box` is part of the UI and so interaction with it. So it should be in the Fragment. The fragment then interacting with the view-model is a reliable way to do things as that's the main home for your logic.

As the **MVVM design pattern** is similar to the well known MVC pattern in that the M (Model) and V (View) are relatively the same. The only difference resides between the C (Controller) and the VM (View Model).

- **Model**

Represents the Data + State + Business logic. It is not tied to the view nor to the controller, which makes it reusable in many contexts.

- **View**

Binds to observable variables and actions exposed by the View Model. It is possible for multiple views to bind to a single View Model.

- **View Model**

Responsible for wrapping the model and preparing observable data needed by the view. It also provides hooks for the view to pass events to the model. An important thing to keep in mind is that the View Model is not tied to the view.

[**Source**](https://medium.com/@husayn.hakeem/android-by-example-mvvm-data-binding-introduction-part-1-6a7a5f388bf7)

Comment: I explain my point of view about your question "Yes this is what I am doing in my code above, but I don't know if this is the best practice way to do it with Dialog – DIRTY DAVE"